# Is the Cache Storage in a PWA secure?

Tags: javascript, security, caching, progressive-web-apps, web-deployment

I am building a PWA and I have got restrictions that cached data have to be secure in some way, so I was wondering where the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Cache) stores the data.

Since this feature is only available in Secure Contexts (HTTPS), we are protected against man in the middle attacks.

My main concern is that the cache could be accessible by other domains or through the users filesystem, where i suppose the data is stored. Sadly there is no documentation about this.

To provide more insight into my application:

- PWA running on a nginx
- .NET Backend running on the same domain and is accessible by appending "/api"

I am aware that I can navigate to the Cache Storage in the Chrome Dev Tools for example, but I do not know where they are stored, and whether they are encrypted or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting question! I don't see any requirement that they be encrypted in the spec (for instance, [here](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-objects) or [here](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#security-considerations)), so I don't think I'd rely on it. Since they would be decrypted by your app when running anyway, you could encrypt and decrypt in your app's code, but that's of limited utility (basically just encrypted at rest when on disk, but not protected from snooping otherwise).

Comment: Define "secure". "Secure" against what exactly?

Comment: @deceze I edited my question to describe my main concerns

Comment: The data is stored on the user's computer and readable by the user's computer (browser); there's no way the user *cannot* access it on disk in some form or another. It would require the use of a secure TPM for that not to be the case, and unless an API explicitly makes such promises, you shouldn't expect that.

Comment: @deceze Is this data stored in plaintext? So basically, if the users computer got compromised, the attacker would be able to view all cached data from the application?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If the user's computer is compromised, you should expect any and all data on it to be compromised. Even if it's encrypted at rest, the key to decrypt it must be on the same disk, because the browser is transparently decrypting it. Again, a TPM might change that equation, but unless it's explicitly promised, you can't expect it.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I suppose you are right. Do you have any information regarding the cache to be accessible by other domains?

Comment: Can you restrict your question to that specific aspect, how the cache API interacts  with different origins…? That's an answerable question.

Comment: And the answer to it is: No, other domains cannot access your cached data (modulo browser bugs). From my [first link above](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-objects): *"Caches are not shared across origins, and they are completely isolated from the browser’s HTTP cache."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you both. I think I have enough information acquired and ready to speak with my security team about that issue. I would ask one of you to sum up the two answers (deceze's about compromised computers and your last) so that I can accept it, in case other people stumble across this issue